# Simple ListView project is crashing, but no errors are shown

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

There are no errors in the message console when I run my project but it keeps crashing.  I couldn't spot the reason.  I tried to go through some of the similar questions asked and did implement the given solutions but it still didn't help me.  Here is my code.

```
package com.example.omar.quakereport;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EarthquakeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView earthquakeListView;
    ArrayList<String> earthquakes;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//    public static final String LOG_TAG = EarthquakeActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earthquake_activity);

        // Create a fake list of earthquake locations.
        earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();
        earthquakes.add("San Francisco");
        earthquakes.add("London");
        earthquakes.add("Tokyo");
        earthquakes.add("Mexico City");
        earthquakes.add("Moscow");
        earthquakes.add("Rio de Janeiro");
        earthquakes.add("Paris");

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        earthquakeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, earthquakes);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        earthquakeListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

This is the class that houses my getters:

```
package com.example.omar.quakereport;

public class Earthquakes {
    private String mMagnitude;
    private String mLocation;
    private String mDate;

    public Earthquakes(String magnitude, String location, String date){
        mMagnitude = magnitude;
        mLocation = location;
        mDate = date;
    }

    public String getMagnitude(){
        return mMagnitude;
    }

    public String getLocation(){
        return mLocation;
    }

    public String getDate(){
        return mDate;
    }
```

This is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And this is my list item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Look in the "Android Monitor" tab at the bottom of Android Studio, make sure "Verbose" is selected in the drop down and that there is nothing (i.e. no filter) in the search box immediately to the right of the drop down. If your app is crashing, there should be something there.

Comment: This is from a Udacity course. I assume you haven't gotten to the point where the earthquakes are moved from the arraylist to the earthquake class? We need to know what error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListViews do not have an orientation attribute.

You should wrap the ListView in a Relative/Linear/Frame-Layout

Then, you need to use an `ArrayAdapter<Earthquake> adapter;` ([see here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)) (and make your class name singular). Alternatively, you need to implement `toString()` on the Earthquake class, as that is what the `ArrayAdapter<String>` uses to display the data.

And, then *edit* the item layout to add TextViews to display and EarthQuake data, and finally *use* the earthquake item xml layout, not `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Once you have that adapter, you can actually do this to add and display data

```
adapter.add(new Earthquake("magnitude", "location", "date"));
```

Comment: This doesn't address the crash issue since we don't yet gave a stack trace.

Comment: True, but it addresses enough of the problem since I'm not seeing anything that could be null or any other obvious mistakes